# What would make the_date function in wordpress only show up on random posts

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a website for a client and I specifically needed to modify a given wordpress template. The template uses the get_template_part function to call the content. So for the loop on the index page it should be showing the_date under the header but for some reason it is showing up on some of the posts and not all.

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- Content -->
    <div class="container contentarea">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column-content">
                <div id="content" role="main">
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <!-- Call content.php -->
                        <?php get_template_part( 'content' ); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div class="paging">
                        <?php     if(function_exists('lugada_kriesi_pagination')) : lugada_kriesi_pagination(); else:  ?>
                        <?php global $wp_query; $total_pages =     $wp_query->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 1 ) { ?>
                            <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                                <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__( '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Older posts', 'newzeo' )) ?></div>    
                                <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'newzeo' )) ?></div>    
                            </div>
                        <?php } endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php else : ?>

                        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                            <header class="entry-header">
                                <h1 class="entry-title">Nothing Found</h1>
                            </header>
                            <div class="entry-content">
                                <p>Sorry, we can't find post you request. Please try search for a related post.</p>

                                </div>
                            </article>

                        <?php endif; ?>


                </div> <!-- #content -->
            </div> <!-- .column-content -->
            <div class="column-sidebar nomargin">
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

content.php

```
<div class="content-box bucket">

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" >

            <h2 class="entry-header">

                <div class="entry-meta clearfix" >

                    <!-- Sticky post -->
                    <?php if (is_sticky()) : ?>
                    <div class="sticky-label"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <!-- Post title -->
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                </div> <!-- .entry-meta -->

            </h2> <!-- .header -->

            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="entry-content clearfix" itemprop="description">
                <?php the_date('','<p><strong>','</strong></p>',true); ?> 
                <?php the_content('Continue reading'); ?>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array('before' => '<div class="page-link"> <span> Pages: </span>', 'after' => '</div>')); ?>   
            </div>

            <div class="entry-meta footerbox" >
                <!-- Category -->
                <span class="cat-links">
                    <span>Posted in</span>
                    <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?>
                </span>

                <!-- If single & have tag -->
                <!-- Tag -->
                <?php if ( is_single() ): if (has_tag()) : ?>
                <span class="sep"> | </span>
                <span class="tag-links">
                    <span>Tagged</span>
                    <?php echo get_the_tag_list('',', ',''); ?>
                </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '<span class="edit-link"><span class="sep"> | </span>', '</span>'); ?>
                <div class="socialshareboxsingle clearfix">
                    Share this post, let the world know <?php lugada_social_button();?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div> <!-- .footer -->



        </div> <!-- article  -->

</div>
<hr class="post-shadow"/>

<!-- If its single, a user has filled out their description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries -->
<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
<?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) && ( ! function_exists( 'is_multi_author' ) || is_multi_author() ) ) :  ?>
<div class="content-box">   
    <div id="author-info">

        <div id="author-avatar">
            <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), 80 ); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="author-description">
            <h2 >About <?php echo get_the_author(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>
        </div>  

        <div id="author-link" class="clearfix">
            <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'user_url' )) : ?>
            <span>Add my circles on Google+ : </span>
            <span itemprop="author"><a href="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url' ); ?>?rel=author" rel="me"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a></span>
            <br/>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>">
            View all posts by <?php echo get_the_author(); ?><span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="post-shadow"/>
<?php endif; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not random posts. Read the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date):

> When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag [the_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time) or [get_the_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_date) (since 3.0) with a [date-specific format string](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time).

Change:

```
<?php the_date('','<p><strong>','</strong></p>',true); ?>
```

To:

```
<p><strong><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></strong></p>
```